# Google Play Services Library Error при использовании Onesignal

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-play-services

Для отправления нотификаций использую [Onesignal](http://onesignal.com) и [документацию](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup) для Android SDK. 
Все сконфигурировал и настроил. Но есть одна проблема... Не могу отправить уведомление устройству, т.к. в учетной записи получаю такой вот текст:

[image: Google Play Services Library Error]

Скажите пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано? Как проверить этот **Conflict plugins**?

P.S. При использовании инициализации Onesignal, используется такой код:

```
 OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
        .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
        .init();
```

при его использовании появляется ошибка:

```
E/OneSignal: Error Getting Google Registration ID
                      java.io.IOException: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
                      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
                      at com.onesignal.PushRegistratorGPS$2.run(PushRegistratorGPS.java:161)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```